# React useEffect not running after all DOM has loaded

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react Application where I am trying to add the AWS Chat Widget.

It is working but I want to add some additional styling to the launch icon which doesnt seem to be their out of the box - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/customize-widget-launch.html

I want too add a tool tip as I have mocked up in the image:

[image]

This is the code I have added to useEffect method:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const widgetEle =  document.getElementById('amazon-connect-chat-widget');
    debugger;
    if (widgetEle) {
      widgetEle.innerHTML = '<span class="tooltip-text" id="left">Chat with us!<button id="chatToolTipClose" type="button" class="close">x</button></span>';
    }
 }, []);
```

I thought this should only run after the DOM has fully rendered - but on my debugger the widgetEle is always null.  But when I run the exit the debugger the default google chat icon is displayed - and when I inspect the element I can see there is no typo in the id - it is exactly what I specify.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a timing issue, and at the time, useEffect executes the widget is not present on the page hence why it is always null, what I suggest is to do script.onLoad to ensure that the widget is present in the dom. Can you also add the code where you call the actual widget script?

Comment: script on Load within the useEffect?  I can give that a go